# Figuring out automorphism groups

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering what tactics people usually use to figure out automorphism groups. Let's start with small finite groups. For example, I'm trying to figure out $\mathrm{Aut}(V_4)$. My thought process would be the following: $V_4$ is generated by two elements, $a$ and $b$, so any automorphism would be determined by where these two elements map. So now I have four elements $a$ and $b$ can each map to. But I know they can't map to the identity (otherwise the automorphism wouldn't be injective). The automorphism also has to satisfy the homomorphism criterion. By testing each of the 6 possible permutations of $a$, $b$, and $c = ab$, I find that these are all automorphisms, so I see that $\mathrm{Aut}(V_4) = S_3$.

But that process seems very brute-force. I certainly can't go through this process for larger groups. Are there any other methods? For example, what if I chose $S_3$ to begin with and found some isomorphism between $\mathrm{Aut}(V_4)$ and $S_3$? Is there a way to accurately guess a group action of $S_3$ on $V_4$ (and then prove the action is faithful)?

Thanks! I'm new to math stackexchange but have been here a few times before to read posts, so please let me know if there is anything wrong with my posts (e.g. too long, too apologetic...).

Comment: A theorem which is often very useful is that $G/Z(G)\cong Inn(G)$ where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $Inn(G)$ is the inner automorphism group  of $G$ (that is the group of conjugation actions of $G$ on itself). Often the harder part then is determining the outer automorphism group $Aut(G)/Inn(G)$.

Comment: Yeah, if I just have my group G, I can find the center pretty easily, but then as you said, I still don't know what the outer automorphism group is. Maybe I could look at a larger group $H$ containing $G$, e.g. for finite $G$, maybe look at the smallest symmetric group $S_n$ that contains $G$, and use $H$ to act on $G$ or cosets of subgroups of $G$ via conjugation, in order to find the outer automorphisms? I'm not even sure if this will definitely uncover all the outer automorphisms. [cont]

Comment: [cont'd] Maybe $H$ would have to be something like $S_{|G|}$ acting on $|G|$ by conjugation, but then I'd have to check which are actually _group_ actions, i.e. $S_{|G|}$ acting on $G$. This approach should theoretically reveal all possible outer automorphisms (I think...), but it is again probably extremely tedious...

Comment: Oops, where I italicized _group_ I meant "action on the group". Hopefully it was clear that $S_{|G|}$ was still a group!

Comment: One of the techniques I've seen in the description of the outer automorphisms of $S_6$ is to study conjugacy classes, as exotic automorphisms may exchange them.

Comment: New idea, similar to @JHance looking at conjugacy classes: Eliminate possibilities by knowing a set of generators and the order of each of the generators. Generators of order $k$ can only be mapped to other elements of order $k$... That would be like looking at cyclic subgroups. Eliminate some more by maybe having a presentation of the group, so that to check the homomorphism properties you would only need to check the relations given in the presentation.